# Understanding GCC's output of `-fmem-report`

Tags: gcc

How should I interpret the output given by GCC's `-fmem-report` flag?

What information can I retrieve from the table and subsequent statistics?

I've tried retrieving the peak memory consumption during compilation and thought intuitively, that the last line of the table (`Total`) gives me the value. But these are far from the ones I've seen in `top`.
While compiling my project, the highest peak from `gcc` processes was around 1.7GB, but the biggest value I can find in the build log is around 750MB.

What other GCC flags can help me in monitoring these ~1.7GB? Or do I need to wrap `make` inside a script monitoring `gcc` and `ld` processes?

Given the following output, what values are the most important and most informative?

```
Memory still allocated at the end of the compilation process
Size   Allocated        Used    Overhead
8             40k         38k       1200 
16           104k        100k       2288 
32           296k        295k       5328 
64            20k         16k        320 
128         4096         384          56 
256           48k         45k        672 
512          188k        187k       2632 
1024         888k        887k         12k
2048         156k        154k       2184 
4096         188k        188k       2632 
8192          56k         48k        392 
16384         16k         16k         56 
32768         32k          0          56 
65536         64k          0          56 
131072        128k        128k         56 
24           236k        232k       4248 
40            36k         33k        576 
48            12k       8496         192 
56          4096        2016          64 
72            12k       8136         168 
80          4096         480          56 
88          1448k       1429k         19k
96            12k         10k        168 
112         4096        1568          56 
120         8192        5040         112 
184           16k         14k        224 
160         4096         960          56 
168           36k         35k        504 
152           56k         51k        784 
104         4096         416          56 
352          516k        486k       7224 
136         4096         408          56 
Total       4640k       4424k         63k

String pool
entries     16631
identifiers 16631 (100.00%)
slots       32768
deleted     0
bytes       252k (17592186044415M overhead)
table size  256k
coll/search 0.4904
ins/search  0.0345
avg. entry  15.55 bytes (+/- 9.75)
longest entry   66

??? tree nodes created

(No per-node statistics)
Type hash: size 1021, 27 elements, 0.140351 collisions
DECL_DEBUG_EXPR  hash: size 1021, 0 elements, 0.000000 collisions
DECL_VALUE_EXPR  hash: size 1021, 0 elements, 0.000000 collisions
no search statistics
decl_specializations: size 61, 0 elements, 0.000000 collisions
type_specializations: size 61, 0 elements, 0.000000 collisions
No gimple statistics

Alias oracle query stats:
  refs_may_alias_p: 0 disambiguations, 0 queries
  ref_maybe_used_by_call_p: 0 disambiguations, 0 queries
  call_may_clobber_ref_p: 0 disambiguations, 0 queries

PTA query stats:
  pt_solution_includes: 0 disambiguations, 0 queries
  pt_solutions_intersect: 0 disambiguations, 0 queries
```

Comment: Wonder it works with `17592186044415M overhead`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output shows what memory was used during the compilation.  GCC/G++ allocates memory in various sized chunks, based on need.

Take the first entry, for example:

```
Size   Allocated        Used    Overhead
8             40k         38k       1200
```

This shows that 40K of memory was allocated in 8-byte chunks, of that 40K, 38K was USED by the compiler, and 1200 bytes were 'accounting overhead'.  Malloc(3) doesn't always return exactly what you ask for, there's usually a teeny couple of bytes indicating how big this chunk is, various accounting data (who owns this chunk), and if things need to be aligned, there may be unused bytes too.

Basically, this information is just accounting notes.

The hash table stuff near the end is showing how the well hash routine worked, to allow GCC/G++ to find things in its tables, how many collisions occurred (same hash value), which needed to be handled, and so forth.

I do like the 'bytes' entry in the 'String Pool':

```
bytes       252k (17592186044415M overhead)
```

HOW much memory does it take to store strings? OMG!!  And that's MEGABytes. {Grin}  Might be a bug. Might not... how much ram you got?

Overall, GCC/G++ used 1.7GB during your compilation because that was available, consider also, did you use multiple/parallel compilation? (-j switch), that'll add up usage, since the parallel programs don't talk to each other.  Compiling the same with 512M of RAM available would just take longer since GCC/G++ would have to stop and clean up more often to keep enough RAM available.

If you wanted to see how it reacts under smaller memory constraints, have a look at the **ulimit** command, especially the *d*, *v*, *m* and maybe *l* limits.  Remember to use the *-S* (soft limits) switch too, or you'll have to close the terminal/console/konsole to regain unlimited limits. (sounds like a marketing plan there)

Comment: Thanks for your time and that answer.
I've got 4GB of memory and didn't do parallel compilation as that would lead to extensive swapping and a unusable computer for about half an hour.
Yeah, these `17592...M` are really weird.
I'll try playing around with `ulimit`. Thanks for that hint.

Answer (score 0):

fmem-report is defined in common.opt file in gcc source code. You can use ctags and cscope to get the actual file which is setting fmem-report flag and then you need to look the code which is checking this flag. If you dont get this let me know I will find it